# Contact form in a facebook page/tab

Tags: php, facebook, forms

I need to create a contact form in a Facebook tab, that is supposed to store every entry/submission in a MySQL database. But i'm quite stuck.

Doing the HTML part, creating the form and the inputs wasn't that hard, but the main problem comes from the iFrame/HTML applications from Facebook (i used some already - popular - made apps that i found around).

I cannot include PHP into the Facebook tab, because it's only has support for html/css/js. I tried using  but failed, as they are not displaying their source inside the Facebook tabs, so how am i supposed to accomplish this task?

LE: I managed to self-sign a certificate. Now the application is starting, as i provided secured URLs, but instead of loading the index.php in that directory i pointed, it gives me a 404 of the main site.

The main site is quart.ro, the url/secured urls are: http://quart.ro/beautydistrict and https://quart.ro/beautydistrict.

Should i write an .htaccess only for that folder? Or should i change the urls to point directly to the file ex: http/s://quart.ro/beautydistrict/index.php/?

LE2: On the application's page - https://apps.facebook.com/beautydistrict/ - it displays the content correctly (this content - http://quart.ro/beautydistrict). This app is a page tab. If i install the app to a facebook page, then instead of displaying the content correctly it gives the 404 of the main website (intead of http://quart.ro/beautydistrict i get http://www.quart.ro/404).

Comment: Can you share the app that you used in creating your pagetab?AFAIK, if it allows you to create an iFrame that loads a page, then you can do anything you want inside that pagetab, just put the url of the domain where you store the form. Anyway, here is a reference, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Aren't tabs iframes to your own server? Where is your page hosted?

Comment: @Hendyanto i used someone's else app, like an already made-app for iframes (you can find a dozen if you search for html/iframe on fb).That's when i tried using the <iframe> tags. Then i created myself an app, but facebook only imports secured urls into the pagetab, and i do not own a ssl certificate.This is the app i made, but it is not working as the secured links are not good, and without a SSL certificate, it will not display anything/get me an error.
https://apps.facebook.com/beautydistrict/

Comment: @MathieuImbert How can i host on my server the tabs that are supposed to be integrated in facebook? On my server i have a .php file, which contains a form, and all the php code to handle the inputs. I somehow must include that file into a FB tab or at least include the code.

Comment: @Darkkz Sorry for late reply, but it is true that facebook require secure connection, and it is a must, last time i ended setting up a secure connection on my server :)

Comment: @Hendyanto Please check the original post, i updated with infos after i got a self-signed certificate. Thanks :)

Comment: but I still got this error..
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

You can post your html data into external PHP file using jquery and ajax. Use this guide http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/